# WPF application controls don't resize after minimize

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resize

i'm developing a WPF Application; my problem is when i maximise windows and after i minimize / resize it; the control, on maximise going well but when i minimize/resize window, control(textblock, combobox) don't and maintain maximized dimension.
how can i make my control resize on minimise?

Here a semple of my XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.UC.Suppliers_Insert"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.UC"
         xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
 <DockPanel Name="MainDock" LastChildFill="True" DataContext="{Binding Suppliers_Insert, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Height="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Name="wRow0" Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Name="wRow1" Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Name="wRow2" Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Name="wRow3" Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Name="wRow4" Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" WatermarkContent="Supplier Name" Text="{Binding SupplierModel.Supplier_Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                         Style="{StaticResource RadWatermarkTextBoxStyle_UserNamme}" Margin="5,5,5,0" Visibility="{Binding Supplier_Name_Visibility}" IsEnabled="{Binding Supplier_Fields_Enable}"
                                         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplateError}"/>

            <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" WatermarkContent="Vat Number" Text="{Binding SupplierModel.VAT_Number, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                         Style="{StaticResource RadWatermarkTextBoxStyle_UserNamme}" Margin="5,5,5,0" Visibility="{Binding VAT_Number_Visibility}" IsEnabled="{Binding Supplier_Fields_Enable}"
                                         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplateError}"/>

            <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" WatermarkContent="Tax Code" Text="{Binding SupplierModel.Tax_Code, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                         Style="{StaticResource RadWatermarkTextBoxStyle_UserNamme}" Margin="5,5,5,0" Visibility="{Binding Tax_Code_Visibility}" IsEnabled="{Binding Supplier_Fields_Enable}"
                                         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplateError}"/>

            <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" WatermarkContent="External Supplier ID" Text="{Binding SupplierModel.External_Supplier_ID, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                         Style="{StaticResource RadWatermarkTextBoxStyle_UserNamme}" Margin="5,5,5,0" Visibility="{Binding External_Supplier_ID_Visibility}" IsEnabled="{Binding Supplier_Fields_Enable}"
                                         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplateError}"/>

            <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" WatermarkContent="Note" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="{Binding SupplierModel.Note, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                         Style="{StaticResource RadWatermarkTextBoxStyle_UserNamme}" Margin="5,5,5,0" Visibility="{Binding Note_Visibility}" IsEnabled="{Binding Supplier_Fields_Enable}"
                                         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplateError}"/>

            <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" WatermarkContent="Website" Text="{Binding SupplierModel.Website, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                         Style="{StaticResource RadWatermarkTextBoxStyle_UserNamme}" Margin="5,5,5,0" Visibility="{Binding Website_Visibility}" IsEnabled="{Binding Supplier_Fields_Enable}"
                                         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplateError}"/>


            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="rdb_Insert" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{DynamicResource rsBtn_Insert}" Width="75" 
                               Visibility="{Binding InsertButtonVisibility}" Command="{Binding SaveNavigationCommand}" />
            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="rdb_Cancel" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{DynamicResource rsBtn_Cancel}" Width="75" 
                               Command="{Binding CancelNavigationCommand}" Visibility="{Binding CancelButtonVisibility}" />
            <telerik:RadButton x:Name="rdb_Close" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                   Content="{DynamicResource rsBtn_Close}" Width="75" Command="{Binding CancelButtonVisibility}" Visibility="{Binding CloseButtonVisibility}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to indicate that UC is into a StackPanel in my MainView. I've change the SP to a Grid and now content will resize correctly when windows minimise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did debugging of your usercontrol and for that i have to remove the command and styles you have used in the xaml. I can able to see the controls minimize or maximize on window resize. I am sure the problem is with your styles you have applied to the controls.
The code i have used is:

```
 <DockPanel Name="MainDock" LastChildFill="True" 
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Height="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Name="wRow0" Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Name="wRow1" Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Name="wRow2" Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Name="wRow3" Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Name="wRow4" Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" WatermarkContent="Supplier Name" Text="{Binding SupplierModel.Supplier_Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                          Margin="5,5,5,0" Visibility="{Binding Supplier_Name_Visibility}" IsEnabled="{Binding Supplier_Fields_Enable}"
                                         />

                <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" WatermarkContent="Vat Number" Text="{Binding SupplierModel.VAT_Number, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                          Margin="5,5,5,0" Visibility="{Binding VAT_Number_Visibility}" IsEnabled="{Binding Supplier_Fields_Enable}"
                                         />

                <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" WatermarkContent="Tax Code" Text="{Binding SupplierModel.Tax_Code, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                         Margin="5,5,5,0" Visibility="{Binding Tax_Code_Visibility}" IsEnabled="{Binding Supplier_Fields_Enable}"
                                         />

                <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" WatermarkContent="External Supplier ID" Text="{Binding SupplierModel.External_Supplier_ID, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                         Margin="5,5,5,0"
                />

                <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" WatermarkContent="Note" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="{Binding SupplierModel.Note, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                         Margin="5,5,5,0" 
                />

                <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" WatermarkContent="Website" Text="{Binding SupplierModel.Website, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                          Margin="5,5,5,0"  
                                         />


                <telerik:RadButton x:Name="rdb_Insert" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"   Width="75" 
                                />
                <telerik:RadButton x:Name="rdb_Cancel" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="75" 
                               />
                <telerik:RadButton x:Name="rdb_Close" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                   Width="75"  />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
```